# Why using eax instead of rax in my program?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

This program is used to calculate the sum and average of all the elements in *arr*. It is done by a function called *stats1*.

```
%include "io64.inc"

global stats1
stats1:
push r12

mov rax,0 ;running sum
mov r12,0 ;index

sumLoop:
add rax,[rdi+r12*8]
inc r12
cmp r12,rsi
jl sumLoop

mov dword [rdx],eax

cdq
idiv esi
mov dword [rcx],eax

pop r12
ret

section .data
arr dq 1,2,3
len dq 3
sum dq 0
ave dq 0

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
mov rdi,arr
mov rsi,[len]
mov rdx,sum
mov rcx,ave

call stats1

PRINT_DEC 8, sum
NEWLINE
PRINT_DEC 8, ave
```

Why I need to use `eax` instead of `rax` in line 16? In my case, I first assign the address of *sum* into `rdx`. `rax` is used as running sum and after the *sumLoop* which calculates the sum, I assign the value of it to `rdx` which is essentially the variable *sum*. I first used `rax` instead of `eax` in line 16 and I got the error output of *sum*, 0. Why when I use `eax`, the correct output 6 is shown? *sum*, `rax` and `rdx` are all 64 bits, why can't I do this?

Comment: You didn't use `dword` when you _used rax instead of eax in line 16_, did you?

Comment: You should refrain from using size tags like `byte`, `word`, `dword`, etc on anyhing that does not involve litteral numbers. The assembler already knows the size looking at the register names. Exceptions to this rule are `MOVZX` and `MOVSX` with a memory operand.

Comment: More importantly, if you're writing a function that takes pointer args, you need to know what size the pointed-to integers are, and use the right size.  You don't want to write outside the caller's object with a too-large store, and you don't want to leave some bytes unwritten holding garbage with a too-small store.  Just like in C when you write `void foo(int64_t *arr, int64_t len, int *ptotal, int *pavg)` (to match what your function is doing), it would be super wrong to do `*(int64_t*)ptotal = sum;` in the function body.

Comment: However, your caller *is* passing pointers to static `dq` qwords, so you should be doing 64-bit math (`cqo`/`idiv`) and 64-bit stores.  Or better, return the integers in RDX and RAX, and let the caller store them or use them directly.  Also, you don't need to use call-preserved R12, you could use any of the call-clobbered registers for your loop counter, e.g. one of R8..R11.